# Check Array length - giv me a [0] in array

Tags: angularjs, arrays

that's how I'll get some data via get url, it appears on the page. But when I eg select two or just one.

When I get elected them I need / set as the me this:

> Array[0]

Angularjs:

```
var url = "/JsonClass/ColorAddToUppers";
$http.get(url).success(function (response) {
    $scope.ColorAddUppers = response;
});


//Overdel
$scope.NextLvlThree = function () {
    //Check Color Values

    $scope.selectedTextValuesByWatch = [];

    $scope.$watchCollection('ColorAddUppers|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv, ov) {
        $scope.selectedTextValuesByWatch = nv.filter(function (value) {
            return value.selected;
        }).map(function (value) {
            return value.Text;
        });
    }, true);

    $scope.getSelectedTextValues = function () {
        return $scope.ColorAddUppers.filter(function (value) {
            return value.selected;
        }).map(function (value) {
            return value.Text;
        });
    }

    console.log($scope.selectedTextValuesByWatch);

    if ($scope.selectedTextValuesByWatch.length > 0)
    {
        alert('Succes!');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Given array is empty!');
    }

}
```

Error:
Every time I eg just choose one so give it to me this one error

> Given array is empty!

What I would want it to do it is such as to tell me how many you just chose for the individual areas.

Comment: The English is so bad in this question it's almost impossible to understand what you're even asking.

Comment: sorry @Coop im not good to to English...

Comment: Then use a translation service. Can't make any sense out of this at all